# window location replace works only one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is very complicated term for me because i am confused how things are done. I have React & Express application where you can upload data and when you upload it will redirect you to other page where your data is displayed, but problem is that it only redirects you one time and when you go back to main page and try to upload file second time it is not uploaded and whole application crashes

here is recipe.js file (part of it) (react)

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/recipes',
  config: {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }},
  data: data
})
.then(res => {
  window.location.replace(res.data.location)
})
.catch(err => {
   if(err.response){
     if(err.response.data.redirect === true){
       window.location.replace(err.response.data.location)
     }
     if(err.response.data.message){
       alert(err.response.data.message)
     }
   }
});
```

recipe.js (part of it)(expressjs)

```
const recipe = await Dish.create({
  author: user.username,
  name: name,
  //properties and values
})


return res.status(200).send({  
  location: '/recipe/' + recipe.name + '/' + recipe._id
})
```

view-recipe.js (express (part))

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    console.log(`/api/recipe/${params.dishName}/${params.id}`)
    axios.get(`/api/recipe/${params.dishName}/${params.id}`)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data =>{
       console.log(data)
    }).catch(err=>{
        if(err.response.data.message){
        alert(err.response.data.message)
        }
    })      
}
```

view-recipe.js (express)

```
router.get('/:dishName/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const name = req.params.dishName;
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log('name ' + name + '  id  ' + id)
    const recipe = await Dish.findOne({
      name: name,
      _id: id
    }).lean();
    if (!recipe) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'recipe not found'
      })
    }
    return res.status(200).send({
      recipe
    })
  } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
      })
    }
 })
```

and finally

index.js (express, for where is guard determinig whether jwt validation token is expired or not and route configurations )

```
router.use('/api/recipes', guardr, require('./recipe'))
router.use('/api/recipe', require('./view-recipe'))
```

What is wrong with this code? By the way, before `window.location.replace()` in recipe.js file (client) i had `window.location.href` instead and it worked 2 times. it is really confusing for me because i am doing this difficult project for the first time. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) in a react application

Comment: this is old question but thank you